Html5 video does not always show shadow dom?
While testing a mobile app on IOS, I noticed that sometimes the video tag shows children sources tags, and sometimes it shows a shadow content DOM instead when I use Safari web inspector.
Is there a reason why we sometimes see one over the other?
ex:
<video playsinline preload=auto>
#shadowcontent(user-agent)
<div class="media-controls-container">
<div class="media-controls">
</div>
</div>
</video>

ex2.
<video playsinline preload=auto>
<source src={src} type="video/mp4" />
<source src={src} type="video/webm" />
</video>

I looked up on Mdn and I understand that video tag inherently uses Shadow DOM to hide the controls. But if I don't change my safari inspect settings, why would I sometimes see one thing vs another on DOM inspection?
I recently changed our code from using solely video tag to using video + source tags and I wonder if this is why.
Note: these are not always the same src string, could that do anything? I'm certainly not creating any logic to add any shadow doms.
